# how to prevent combobox enforcing data from database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

My **combobox is filled** with **data source** from my DB, but when I try to **edit/update** the data from datagridview from **another form**, it keeps selecting the **first item** in the DB **which is filled with**. It doesn't select another data outside the filling source. combobox name is suppliername.

This is the form where I add something to the database (more specifically, it's the code to fill the combobox with data):
pck is a new instance name for a class that calls a stored procedure from DB called get_all_suppliers

```
public frm_add_req_pc()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     suppliername.DataSource = pck.get_all_suppliers();
     suppliername.DisplayMember = "suppliername";
     suppliername.ValueMember = "suppliername";
}
```

This is the form where I try to update the combobox:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frm_add_req_pc frm = new frm_add_req_pc();
     frm.suppliername.Text = 
     this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I select data from the dgv, it (the combobox) enforces selecting from filling source. I need to be able to select data that is not in the filling source. Any ideas on how I can do it?

Comment: You are creating a new instance by calling `frm_add_req_pc frm = new frm_add_req_pc();` instead of using the existing one

Comment: yes , i do ... how is this relevant to my issue?

Comment: Suppose your main form is already open; then when you click on the said button in the question, at this moment a new instance of your main form is created. Thus the combobox text whose value is to be set in the existing form instance is not going to set automatically

Comment: I've just tried that but issue remains untouched ... same problem combobox shows data from fill source not from dgv

Comment: Instead of `frm.suppliername.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();` use `frm.suppliername.SelectedValue  = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();` or `frm.suppliername.SelectedItem = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();`. Also make sure the DataGridCellValue does not have trailing spaces or any other character, same goes with the combobox source items

Comment: frm.suppliername.SelectedValue = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
shows blank field in combobox